# Wrapping up a div and anchor tag from given data

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm having a data of countries with description and it's link. I need to wrap each countries description(`<p>`tag) and link (`<a>` tag) inside a div.

When i try to append the  data anchor tag is going inside  the paragraph tag. I need to get the `<p>` tag and anchor tag wrapped inside the div.

```
/*HTML*/ 

 <body>
    <div id="countries">
    </div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

The data is given below

```
  var data = [{
    country: "America",
    href: "/america"
}, {
    country: "France",
    href: "/france"
}];

/*script*/

d3.select("#countries")
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .append("p")
    .text(function(d){return d.country;})
    .append("a")
    .attr('href',function(d){   return d.href;});
```

I have got the results like this the anchor tag inside the `<p>` tag.

```
 <div id="countries">
    <p>
        America
        <a href="#">
        </a>
    </p>
    <p>
        France
        <a href="#">
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm expecting a result like this. Need to get the anchor tag and paragraph wrapped inside each div.

```
 <div id="countries">
    <div>
        <p>
            America
        </p>
        <a href="/america">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            France
        </p>
        <a href="/france">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey NJ_Coder, your expected and current results are the same; not sure if you meant this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observed result is the expected one, since everything is chained in your enter selection.

The solution is just breaking that enter selection, which append divs. Then, you append the `<p>` and `<a>` elements separately:

```js
var data = [{
  country: "America",
  href: "/america"
}, {
  country: "France",
  href: "/france"
}];

var divs = d3.select("#countries")
  .selectAll('div')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div");

divs.append("p")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.country;
  });

divs.append("a")
  .attr('href', function(d) {
    return d.href;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="countries"></div>
```

That will create this structure:

```
<div id="countries">
    <div>
        <p>America</p>
        <a href="/america"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>France</p>
        <a href="/france"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```